# How to format a multiline string?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to format a multi line string in powershell.

```
$json =
@'
{
    "updateDetails": [{
            "datasourceSelector": {
                "datasourceType": "AnalysisServices",
                "connectionDetails": {
                    "server": "{0}"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
'@
$json = [string]::Format($json, $name)
```

The final line gives the error

> Exception calling "Format" with "2" argument(s): "Input string was not in a correct format."

I've also tried the notation `'@  -f $name` but get this error.

> Error formatting a string: Input string was not in a correct format

I've also tried escaping the quotes in the string like this, but get the same error

```
`"{0}`"
```

How do I format a multiline string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[C# Tips and Tricks #7 – Escaping ‘{‘ in C# String.Format](https://developerpublish.com/c-tips-and-tricks-7-escaping-in-c-string-format/)

```
$json =
@'
{{
    "updateDetails": [{{
            "datasourceSelector": {{
                "datasourceType": "AnalysisServices",
                "connectionDetails": {{
                    "server": "{0}"
                }}
            }}
        }}
    ]
}}
'@
[string]::Format($json, $name)
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `-replace` instead of Format:

```
$name = 'MyServer'
$json = @'
{
    "updateDetails": [{
            "datasourceSelector": {
                "datasourceType": "AnalysisServices",
                "connectionDetails": {
                    "server": "{0}"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
'@
$json -replace '\{0}', $name  # the opening curly bracket needs to be escaped
```

Or use double-quotes on the here string and put variable `$name` in it directly:

```
$name = 'MyServer'
$json = @"
{
    "updateDetails": [{
            "datasourceSelector": {
                "datasourceType": "AnalysisServices",
                "connectionDetails": {
                    "server": "$name"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
"@
```